why i cant access to a field (no field on type)

no field main on type impl Future<Output = Result<WeatherData, reqwest::Error>>
unknown field  [E0609]

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct WeatherData {
    main: Main,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct Main {
    temp: Vec<f32>,
}

async fn get_weather() -> Result<WeatherData, reqwest::Error> {
    reqwest::get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=neftekamsk&units=metric&cnt=8&appid=apikeyhere")
        .await?
        .json::<WeatherData>()
        .await
}
fn test() {
    get_weather().main.temp
}


Check you data type, Visibility, and Async function
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct WeatherData {
    pub main: Main,
//  ^
//  L make sure that the field you want to access are public
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct Main {
    pub temp: Vec<f32>,
}

async fn test() {
    get_weather().await.unwrap().main.temp
    //            ^     ^
    //            |     L the return type is Result<WeatherData, reqwest::Error>,
    //            |       need to unwrap before acccessing.
    //            |
    //            L get_weather() is async, you will need to .await for it to finish
}


Given that WeatherData, Main and test share the same module, the fields don't need to be annotated with pub. Fields without a visibility default to being private to the module and its submodules, which means they are already accessible by test.
